# "Хотеть" - совершенный / несовершенный вид

Tags: недопустимая-метка

*Звоните, когда хотите.*

Скажите, пожалуйста, глагол **хотеть** в этом предложении имеет совершенный или несовершенный вид?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-моему, однозначно *несовершенный* вид здесь. А совершенным будет:

> Позвоните, когда ***за***хотите.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь! : )

Comment: Не за что! :) Простите, не знаю, где спросить ещё... А почему Вы не хотите подписаться настоящим именем или хотя бы ником? Конечно, это Ваше право и не моё дело, но мне, например, это было бы приятно. ;)

Comment: : ) Вы будете наверное смеяться когда узнаете мое имя... Меня зовут Sol. (на моем языке это "солнце", на Вашем, насколько я знаю, "соль" ; ) jejeje ... очень приятно, Артём! : )

Comment: Да нет, не буду смеяться, нормальное вроде имя, хоть и короткое.)) Приятно познакомиться! ;) Можно и латиницей написать имя и фамилию, не иероглифы же родные даже, хотя какие-нибудь китайцы пишут преспокойно латиницей имя в сети. Не говорю уже про тех русских, кто почему-то предпочитает на этом сайте имя латиницей несмотря на то, что у них простые русские имена. Я, например, тут по-русски значусь, а на "English language and usage" латиницей, благо один переводчик отсюда подсказал, как это сделать. Но, повторюсь, я ни в коем случае Вам ничего не хочу навязывать!)

Answer (score 0):

"Хотеть" *в любом* предложении глагол совершенного вида.

Anonym, я понимаю, что русский для вас не совсем родной, но - для вашего уровня знания языка - вопросы ваши выглядят странными.

В русском языке очень мало бесприставочных глаголов совершенного вида. Проще их выучить: **дать** (неправильный глагол), несколько глаголов на "-ить" (имеющих видовую пару на -ать): решить, пустить, купить, явить, лишить, бросить, кончить, обидеть, пленить, хватить (парные решать, пускать, являть и т. д.) и несколько двувидовых: венчать, обещать, велеть, женить, казнить, ранить. Вот у этих последних есть проблемы с определением вида в прошедшем времени. "Хотеть" к таковым не относится.

Comment: наверное, Вы хотели сказать, что в любом предложении это глагол **не**совершенного вида.

Comment: Дорогой Behemothus, я повторяюсь: если Вам мои вопросы не нравятся и странными кажутся, не отвечаите, просто проходите мимо!  Saludos